# HTML form select with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Borrowing-Power-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Borrowing Power Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Loan-Repayment-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Loan Repayment Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Lump-Sum-Repayment-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Lump Sum Repayment Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Extra_Repayment_Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Extra Repayment Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Budget-Planner.aspx?ID=MFAA">Budget Planner</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Loan-Comparison-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Loan Comparison Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/How-Long-to-Repay-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">How Long to Repay Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Split-Loan-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Split Loan Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Property-Selling-Cost-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Property Selling Cost Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Property-Buying-Cost-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Property Buying Cost Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Saving-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Saving Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Term-Deposit-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Term Deposit Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Stamp-Duty-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Stamp Duty Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Credit-Card-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Credit Card Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Income-Tax-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Income Tax Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Reverse-Mortgage-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Reverse Mortgage Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Leasing-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Leasing Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Home-Loan-Offset-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Home Loan Offset Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Honeymoon-Loan-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Honeymoon Loan Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Comparison-Rate-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Comparison Rate Calculator</option>
</select>

<script>
  $(function() {
    // bind change event to select
    $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function() {
      var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
      if (url) { // require a URL
        window.location = url; // redirect
      }
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

At the moment, the change of form sends the browser to the URL:
`http://www.visionabacus.com/default.aspx?go=`

I don't understand what needs to change.

Can you help please?

Comment: You couldn't post a shorter example with only three or four option elements?

Comment: The links are redirecting to that page, so either your links are incorrect or the website have broken links

Answer (score 6):

Your code is fine. The links are broken. If you enter them manually you will see that the app on the server side is making a redirection.

Comment: I didn't think to check the redirection ... I was wondering how it ended up with the ?go= URL ... good call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).find(":selected").val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the OP's `$(this).val()` work? In a general sense all modern browsers support the `.value` attribute on select elements.

Comment: I'm not sure ... I just know this is an alternative.  I did not see anything technically wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

i tied this and it worked just fine, so its not the code.

```
<select name="cars" id="dynamic_select">
 <option value="http://www.google.com">Borrowing Power Calculator</option>
</select>

<script>
$(function(){
  // bind change event to select
  $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () {
      var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
      console.log(url);
      if (url) { // require a URL
          window.location = url; // redirect
      }
      return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out, your one is also works fine

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
  // bind change event to select
  $(document).on('change','#dynamic_select', function() {
      var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
      if (url) { // require a URL
         window.location.href = url; // redirect
      }
     return false;
   });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: why would this work if `window.location = url;` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The links are broken in ur option. From the below sample check it with the **second option**.its working.

```
     <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () {
            var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
            if (url) { // require a URL
                window.location = url; // redirect
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" id="dynamic_select">
<option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Borrowing-Power-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Borrowing Power Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261589/html-form-select-with-jquery-not-working">Your Question</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Loan-Repayment-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Loan Repayment Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Lump-Sum-Repayment-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Lump Sum Repayment Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Extra_Repayment_Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Extra Repayment Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Budget-Planner.aspx?ID=MFAA">Budget Planner</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Loan-Comparison-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Loan Comparison Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/How-Long-to-Repay-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">How Long to Repay Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Split-Loan-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Split Loan Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Property-Selling-Cost-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Property Selling Cost Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Property-Buying-Cost-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Property Buying Cost Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Saving-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Saving Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Term-Deposit-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Term Deposit Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Stamp-Duty-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Stamp Duty Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Credit-Card-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Credit Card Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Income-Tax-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Income Tax Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Reverse-Mortgage-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Reverse Mortgage Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Leasing-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Leasing Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Home-Loan-Offset-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Home Loan Offset Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Honeymoon-Loan-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Honeymoon Loan Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Comparison-Rate-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Comparison Rate Calculator</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```